# How to use .Contains with Int DataType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

The code below is part of the search functionality code that grabs the query string from URL and searches the database.

Everything works great except for one thing which is `BatchID`. Which throws the below error message. The `BatchID`is DataType `Int` in the database. Due to this reason it's causing an error. I tried casting as `(string)` however no luck

**Error Message**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1061  'int' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no extension method
>   'Contains' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   CardDistro E:\wwwroot\CardDistro \CardDistro
>   \Controllers\CardsController.cs   32

```
QueriedTransactionList = db.Transactions
                           .Where(x => x.Card.InCome.InComePayerName.Contains(QueryString) || 
                                       x.Card.InCome.InComePayerEmail.Contains(QueryString) ||
                                       x.Card.InCome.InComePayerTIN.Contains(QueryString) ||
                                       x.BatchID.Contains( (string) QueryString) //Error over here || 
                                       x.Card.Port.PortName.Contains(QueryString)
                                  )
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.TTransactionID)
                           .GroupBy(x => x.BatchID)
                           .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BatchID` property is `int` type , you cannot use `Contains`  as it works on an array. You may check the value directly using `==` operator.

Since you are using the same `string` parameter(`QueryString`) to get the id value as well, you should use the `TryParse` method to safely parse the string to an int variable value (*if it is a valid string representation of an int value*) and use that. If your `BatchID` value is always greater than `0`, you can initialize your local variable to 0, and if the querystring has a valid numeric value, parse it and update the local variable and use that in your LINQ expression.

```
int id = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(QueryString, out id))
{
}
var results = db.Transactions
                 .Where(x => x.Card.InCome.InComePayerName.Contains(QueryString) || 
                             x.Card.InCome.InComePayerEmail.Contains(QueryString) ||
                             x.Card.InCome.InComePayerTIN.Contains(QueryString) ||
                             x.Card.Port.PortName.Contains(QueryString) ||
                             x.BatchID == id   
                       )
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.TTransactionID)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.BatchID)
                       .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                       .ToList();
```